# Are the following intransitive verbs, or transitive verbs?

Tags: transitivity

1. When using Cognate objects. eg. "I dreamt **a strange dream**". Is the verb intransitive because 'dreamt' doesn't need the object here, or is it a Transitive because we have an object for the verb.
2. When adding preposition. eg. "All his friends laughed **at** him" - Transitive or Intransitive and why?
3. When using Adverbial object. eg. "The watch cost **nine hundred dollars**". - Transitive or Intransitive and why?

Comment: *Adverbial object* isn't a standard term.  Can you tell us what grammar or textbook you're working with that uses that term?

Comment: Wren and Martin

Comment: @snailboat Wren & Martin, §190: "A noun used adverbially to modify a verb, an adjective, or an adverb denoting time, place, distance, weight, value, etc., is called an Adverbial Object or Adverbial Accusative, and is said to be in the Accusative Case adverbially; as, 'He held the post ten years,' 'I can't wait a moment longer,' 'He went home,' 'He swam a mile,' 'He weighs seven stone,' 'The watch cost fifty rupees.'"

Comment: Adverbial object ?? - A confusion of terms.

Answer (score 2):

I dreamt a strange dream.

The verb dream can be used as a noun, transitive verb, or intransitive verb. In the above sentence, it's a transitive verb; the subject is I and the direct object is "a strange dream".  The sentence, though grammatically correct, sounds old-fashioned.  Usually, you say "I had a strange dream.

All his friends laughed at him.

The phrasal verb in the sentence is a transitive verb; the subject is "all his friends and the direct object is "him".

The watch cost nine hundred dollars.

The verb is transitive; the subject is "the watch" and the direct object is 
nine hundred dollars.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/laugh-at

Comment: I think this analysis is very debatable. "at him" has a preposition,  so it is no direct  object. You ask "at what", not " they laughed  at  +  whom/what". "900 dollars" is a how much indication, you don't ask "whom/what".

Comment: Yeah. I think 'at' is a preposition here, so 'him' is an object of preposition. We can confirm by doing a test. Detach the at+ object part and start the sentence with that. E.g., 'at him they laughed.' It does make sense, so 'at' is a preposition.  With adverbs as particles, the test doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is more more category of verbs other than what you described -transitive, intransitive, and **both**! It depends how you use it.

All my references are from the OALD

So, in your examples:

> "I dreamt a strange dream - the use of 'dream something' there in [sense #2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dream_2)
>
> ["laugh at somebody" seems an idiom](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/laugh-at) - but anyway, transitive
>
> The watch cost nine hundred dollars - *[transitive](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cost_2)*.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/laugh-at

Answer (score 1):

**At** in *Laugh at* is not a preposition. It is a *particle* in the phrasal verb *laugh at*.

*Laugh at* is always transitive, and therefore any sentence in the active voice written with *laugh at* **must** have a direct object, as in

> *0* All his friends **laughed at** him.

The verb is **laugh at**. The direct object of the verb is *him*.

Without a direct object for *laugh at*, the sentence is ungrammatical. For example:

> *00* *All his friends laughed at.

This sentence is ungrammatical. There is no direct object for the verb *laugh at*, which is always transitive.

Another way to say that the verb *laugh at* is "always transitive" is to say that it is always used *transitively* or that it is always used with a direct object. When we say that the verb *laugh at* is not *transitive*, we mean that it cannot be used intransitively (it cannot be used without a direct object (see Sentence *00*)).

This is different from the verb **stand by** The verb *stand by* can be either transitive or intransitive. Another way to say this is that the verb *stand by* can be used either transitively (with a direct object) OR used intransitively (without a direct object). Below, in Sentences 3b and 6b, *stand by* is transitive, or *used transitively* (that is, with a direct object). In Sentences 2 and 4, *stand by* is intransitive or used intransitively (these are just two different ways of saying that *stand by* is used without a direct object). In Sentences 1a, 1b, 3a, and 6a, the verb is *stand*. It is used intransitively in 1a, 3a, and 6a. It is used transitively in 1b.

In the sentence:

> 1a An old beggar **stood** by the gate.

The verb is *stood*. The word *by* is a preposition and it is part of the prepositional phrase *by the gate*. The word *by* is not part of the verb.

Note that in *stand* (past tense: *stood*) can also be used as a transitive verb, that is, it can be used transitively (with a direct object). An example of this is

> 1b The old beggar by the gate could not **stand** the heat.

(*Stand* here means *endure*.)

In

> 2 The old beggar **stood by**.

*Stood by* in this sentence is intransitive (that is, it is used intransitively), as there is no direct object. And *by* is not a preposition but a particle of the phrasal verb *stand by*.

Now, note that the sentence

> 3 *The old beggar stood by me*

is *ambiguous*. It can be analyzed two ways. It can be analyzed as containing the verb *stand* (3a) or *stand by* (3b).

> 3a The old beggar **stood** by me.

The verb is **stand** and in this sentence it is intransitive, or used intransitively, and *by me* is a prepositional phrase (the preposition is *by* and *me* is the object of the preposition).

> 3b The old beggar **stood by** me.

The verb is **stand by** (transitive). Here *me* is the direct object of the verb **stand by**. *By* is a particle in the phrasal verb *stand by*. In this sentence, *by* is not a preposition.

Note you could also have:

> 4 The old beggar **stood by** by the gate.

Here *stand by* is again intransitive, where the first *by* is a particle of the phrasal verb *stand by*, and the second *by* is the preposition in the prepositional phrase *by the gate*.

To get a little bit more complicated, look at Sentence 6:

> 6 *The old beggar stood by me by the gate.*

What is the verb in Sentence 6? Well, just like Sentence 3, Sentence 6 can be analyzed two ways: with the verb as either *stand* (6a)  or *stand by* (6b).

> 6a The old beggar **stood** by me by the gate.

In 6a, the verb is *stand* (past tense: *stood*). It is intransitive or used intransitively. These are two ways of saying that the verb *stand* is not used with a direct object in this sentence. Note that this sentence, there are two prepositional phrases: *by me* and *by the gate*. Both uses of *by* are as a preposition.

> 6b The old beggar **stood by** me by the gate.

In this case, the verb is *stand by* (past tense: *stood by*). It is used transitively, that is, with a direct object. The direct object of *stand by* is *me*. And *by the gate* is the only prepositional phrase in the sentence. In the sentence, the first *by* is not a preposition, it is a *particle*; it is part of the verb *stand by* (past tense: *stood by*). The second *by* is functioning as a preposition in the prepositional phrase *by the gate.*

Comment: As pointed out by Khan, laugh at is a **transitive** phrasal verb as given in http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/laugh-at . Can we call a verb intransitive when it is part of a transitive phrasal verb?

Comment: @Phoenix Are you talking about the verb *laugh*? The verb *laugh* can be either transitive or intransitive (or, in other words, used transitively or intransitively). However, *laugh at* can only be used transitively (with a direct object). In fact, you cannot write *The beggar laughed at*. With this verb, you must actually state the direct object.

Comment: Verbs are called transitive or intransitive. Many verbs can be both. *To laugh* is both. *To laugh at* is only transitive. Therefore it makes no sense to call *laugh* an intransitive verb when talking about *laugh at* (which is only transitive). Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm unable to understand what's the difference between **laugh at** and **stood by**. As per my understanding both are transitive...

Comment: @Phoenix I have edited my answer. *Laugh at* is always transitive (therefore it must always have a direct object in the active voice). *Stand by* can be either transitive or intransitive. *Stand* can also be either transitive or intransitive. *Laugh* can be either transitive (*He laughed a big laugh*) or intransitive (*He laughed.*).

Comment: To say that a verb is transitive can be said a different way: we can also say that the verb is being used transitively. To say that a verb is intransitive really just means that it can be used instransitively. *Laugh at* can only be used transitively, or as a transitive verb. A short way of saying this is that *laugh at* is a transitive verb. (continued next comment)

Comment: To say that a verb is intransitive is just a short way of saying that a verb is (or can be) used intransitively (or used without a direct object). Some verbs can be either transitive  or intransitive (*stand by*), but some verbs (*laugh at*) can only be *transitive*. Another way to say this is that *laugh at* can only be used transitively, or with a direct object. If you use *laugh at* in the active voice without a direct object, the sentence is **ungrammatical** (See Sentence *00* is my answer.)

Comment: Okay, then what about **"He was one of those who were always laughed at."** Or maybe just **"He was always laughed at"** Neither does the sentence have a direct object nor does it need one.

Comment: These sentences are both in the passive voice.

Comment: "Laugh at" is not a phrasal verb. That's why you can't say "All his friends laughed at." "At" is a preposition, indicating the object of the laughter. (There's a peculiar "laugh at" phrasal verb, with stress on "at", but that's not what you're talking about.)

Comment: @BenKovitz I suggest you write your own answer rather than telling me what I am talking about.

Comment: @Phoenix any good dictionary includes *laugh at* as a phrasal verb, meaning to ridicule. See [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/laugh-at-sb-sth)

Comment: @pazzo Thanks for the explanation. I'll learn more about phrasal verbs in some days and get back to you if I'm still uncertain. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I'll post an answer. I posted my comment above to warn people away from being misled by this one. Or, if I'm mistaken, could you explain why "laugh at" is a phrasal verb but "shout at" isn't? That might enlighten a lot of people, including me.

Comment: @Phoenix Not all good dictionaries list _laugh at_ as a phrasal verb. For example, the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106250) (the most authoritative English dictionary), [Oxford On-Line](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laugh), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laugh), and [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=laugh+at) all treat _at_ as an ordinary preposition. (AH also describes a different _laugh at,_ which has a different meaning.) You've wandered into a rat's nest.

Comment: I'm surprised that you, of all people, who convinced me that "the" could end a sentence and that "ago" could start one (for which I am quite grateful), are now saying that 00 is ungrammatical. "Holden's friends never laugh _with,_ oh no, not that mean-spirited bunch of hipsters, and certainly not that evening at the comedy club. All his friends laughed _at._"