# Help me to Identify whether a verb is transitive or intransitive

Tags: transitivity

I was doing an exercice about identifying types of verbs (transitive or intransitive) in a sentence. And I  am confused about a sentence.

> An old baggar stood by the gate.

In the answer for the above sentence, the verb is marked as an **intransitive** verb.

But as per the explanation in the book, a transitive verb is one that passes over a subject to an object. And in the above sentence the object is *gate*.

In the above sentence, is the verb *stood* transitive or intransitive? And how?

Comment: The word *gate* is the object of the preposition *by*. So there is more than one kind of object in English sentences.

Comment: I think you will find [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58070/6951) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ghanshyam, for non-natives like us, there is only one way to learn things in English. ***Memorize*** them. Especially for Indians where we have our own rules to amend the language, there is nothing we can do. Just observe native speakers and their styles and you learn. That's it.

Well, now here, it's an intransitive verb. True. That's because transitive verbs requires something to *transfer*! [I remember that way -transitive transfer, intransitive, no transfer, thanks [grammargirl]](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs)

Said that, intransitive verbs can stand alone without any support. They won't look odd. Say--

> He ***ran***

the sentence is fine *without* any additional information.

But then...

> I ***want***

is 'half'. You want 'what'? So, here, the verb 'want' is transitive which requires something *to transfer*. You add 'what you want' and it is a complete sentence. They call it as an object.

> I ***want*** a car

In your example,

> An old baggar[sic] stood (by the gate)

'by the gate' is an additional information but not necessary to complete the sentence.

Hence, they mark it with 'intransitive'.

---

The verb 'stand' is both transitive and intransitive but in **its general (and most of?) usages**, it's 'transitive'. More information [is on OALD.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stand_1?q=stand)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct object in this sentence, *by the gate* is a prepositional complement in the sentence.

So you answer your question, the verb *to stand* is intransitive.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **stood**, in your example is used intransitively, having the meaning of being placed or situated.

The **gate** is not the object of the verb **stood**.

Consider:

> An old beggar, by the gate, stood.

Answer (score 0):

A where-indication is no object and a direct object has no preposition.

Added

And I would not use the term object for two different things. Actually that is confusion of grammar terms even if the use of "object of a preposition" is frequent. Some use the terms complement, I would prefer a completely new term, perhaps preposition and its connected noun.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>The verb here is actually TRANSITIVE.</strike>

As per my information, we can convert intransitive verbs into transitive by using prepositions with them. Here 'by' preposition does this work.

> An old beggar **stood**.

The above sentence uses stood as an intransitive verb. But,

> An old beggar **stood by**...

becomes incomplete without an object. Hence, here, **stood** is a transitive verb.

I would suggest you consult your teacher or someone knowledgeable in English in your area and ask him. But I would say this is a transitive verb.

For more such examples, check out [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56170/are-the-following-intransitive-verbs-or-transitive-verbs).

Comment: It is not transitive, look at the fourth meaning given here: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stand_1?q=stand

Comment: @Sander So what is **laugh** in "They laughed at me". http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/laugh_1?q=laugh

Comment: In that sentence it is intransitive and 'at me' is an indirect object. However, if you say 'He laughed a mean laugh.', then it is transitive.

Comment: In *They laughed at me*, *me* is the direct object of the phrasal verb *Laugh at.* But in this sentence, *at* is not a preposition, but a particle. (See [my answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58070/6951)). And in *stand by*, *by* is a particle of the intransitive phrasal verb *stand by*. Also @Sander

Comment: Ah yes, I might be mistaken about the verb *laugh at*. In this case *stand by* is not the verb though, right? *Standing* is the verb and *by the gate* is the complement. In the sentence 'He stood by doing nothing' the verb is *stand by*.

Comment: In *He stood by the gate*, the verb is **stand** and it is intransitive because there is no direct object; the sentence contains a prepositional phrase *by the gate.* In *He stood by doing nothing*, the verb is **stand by** and it is intransitive, because there is no direct object. Both sentences contain the word *by*, but *by* does not function the same in both sentences. Also, *stand by* and *stand* are two different verbs. Just as *laugh* and *laugh at* are two different verbs. (continued)

Comment: The difference is that *laugh at* is only transitive; it cannot be used in a sentence without a direct object. The sentence: *He laughed at by the gate* is ungrammatical, because *laugh at* is only transitive and it must have a direct object. But *stand by* can be both transitive and instransitive. See [my answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58070/6951) for sentence examples with *stand by* as both transitive and intransitive.